# Trying to install php 7.3 with httpd 2.4 on centos 6

Tags: apache-2.4, php7, amazon-linux

I have CentOS6-equivalent systems (Amazon Linux original, not Linux 2) that I upgraded to Apache httpd 2.4.

Now I want to upgrade PHP from 7.1 to 7.3.

As far as I can tell, the Remi repo only provides an httpd libphp for 2.2, not 2.4.
Attempting to install php73-php gets an error on dependency httpd-mmn (expects 20051115, but 2.4 provides 20120211).

I haven't found another repo with PHP 7.3 that integrates with httpd 2.4.

It seems like the only way to get PHP 7.3 to work with httpd 2.4 on CentOS 6 is to use FPM (assuming that I don't want to rebuild PHP 7.3 myself).  Is that the case? Or am I missing something?

I know we need to upgrade to Amazon Linux 2 [or Centos 8] before December - that's planned, but it's a bigger job than we want to tackle right now.

Comment: I think FPM is the way to go, some tips on https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/10/25/php-configuration-tips/

Comment: I am working on converting to php-fpm now. We have some exotic rewrite rules that won't carry over easily, like one that uses a RewriteMap that runs a program (on dev, not prod).

Answer (score 1):

Amazon Linux is only loosely based on CentOS, and is not compatible with packages built for RHEL and CentOS. If one happens to install and work, it's a coincidence, not an intention. It was originally forked from CentOS 5! and has diverged ever since, with no guarantees against breakage with any updates.

You need to switch distributions. Amazon Linux and Amazon Linux 2 are not really appropriate distros for much of anyone except possibly Amazon themselves (and I'm not even sure about that). They provide neither stability nor access to the recent software you need to run a web site.

Comment: It may not be guaranteed, but every CentOS-6 compatible repo I've used has worked with Amazon Linux with zero problems.  Seems like a remarkable string of coincidences :-)

Comment: You got really lucky, then. But your luck is running out. Amazon Linux 2 is far less "compatible" and you should expect lots of breakage if you try that. Take this opportunity to dump it and just go to _real_ CentOS. You probably won't get another opportunity for years.

Comment: Seems like a good idea. From experimenting with Amazon Linux 2 it did seem like they felt they needed to make some unnecessary changes.  I'll check out the AWS Community CentOS 7 and 8 distros when the time comes.

Comment: I recommend you go with 8. The new AppStream setup makes it extremely easy to manage your PHP version (and versions of many other things) so staying on e.g. 7.3 is the default and upgrading, say, from 7.3 to 7.4 is easy but you control when it happens.